# Calling WebApi from Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-services, async-await

I am trying to call the following method from the OnStart() method of the windows service, but the windows service starts and stops and throws an error.

```
 static async Task RunAsync()
    {
            LightSpeedContext<RightHireUnitOfWork> _context;
            var client = new HttpClient();

            _context = new LightSpeedContext<RightHireUnitOfWork>("default");

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.xyz.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                "X-SmartToken",
                "1dfaaad541c45031c8b92bfab3ssssssssssb5644c368f3");

            var content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8,
                                "application/json");
            string config = "v1/assessments?status=NEW";
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            try
            {
                response = await client.GetAsync(config);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException httpEx)
            {
                // determine error here by inspecting httpEx.Message         
            }

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ListResult lr = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ListResult>();

                List<SmartRecruiters.AssessmentOrder> lAsmtOrders = lr.content;
```

// Do other processing here

```
            }

    }
```

The OnStart method is as follows:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");

        // Need to call the RunAsync method here...

    }
```

I tried making OnStart async, but it didn't help.  Any thoughts on how I can successfully make the call?

Comment: The RunAsync() method works fine when run from a Windows Console Application Main method using RunAsync().Wait();

Comment: What error it throws?

Comment: I have tried many different ways of calling the async method based on the information in this forum, but the error I seem to be gettting is as follows:Service cannot be started. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at SmartRecruitersService.Service1.<RunAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\Users\sunilkosuri\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NewCustomAsmt\SmartRecruitersService\Service1.cs:line 366

Comment: What is the best way to call the RunAsync() method from the OnStart method?

Comment: Solved it - I used Windows Task Manager and ran this as a task rather than a windows service and everything worked perfectly.